# Delete a property of a dictionary in Python that may or may not be present

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there an easy way to delete a property of a dictionary in Python when it is possible that the property may not be present to begin with?

if the `del` statement is used, a KeyError is the result:

```
a = {}
del a['foo']
>>>KeyError: 'foo'
```

Its a little wordy to use an if statement and you have to type `'foo'` and `a` twice :

```
a = {}
if 'foo' in a:
    del a['foo']
```

Looking for something similar to `dict.get()` that defaults to a `None` value if the property is not present:

```
a = {}
a.get('foo')  # Returns None, does not raise error
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`dict.pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop), which allows you to specify a default value to return if the key does not exist:

```
>>> d = {1:1, 2:2}
>>> d.pop(1, None)
1
>>> d
{2: 2}
>>> d.pop(3, None)  # No error is thrown
>>> d
{2: 2}
>>>
```